# How to integrate Symfony SimpleCmsBundle in my current project?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-cmf

I am planning to integrate [SimpleCmsBundle](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/SimpleCmsBundle) into my existing Symfony2 project.

How i can import the dependencies through composer?

My current application's `composer.json` file is in the root folder, just like default symfony2.

So, do I need to copy the content of `composer.json` within SimpleCmsBundle into the content of my current default composer, which is in root directory?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `"symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle": "1.3.*@dev"` into your current project composer.json under require.

https://packagist.org/packages/symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle